# Get decltype of function

Tags: c++, decltype

I want to get the type of a function and create a `std::vector` of it. For example, I have

```
int foo(int a[], int n) { return 1; }
int bar(int a[], int n) { return 2; }
```

and a vector of functions like this would be:

```
std::vector< std::function<int(int[],int)> > v;
```

And in general, a `decltype()` would be better, like:

```
std::vector< decltype(foo) > v;
```

however, this will result in a compilation error.

I guess the reason is that `decltype()` cannot distinguish between

```
int (*func)(int[], int)
std::function<int(int[], int)>
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use either:

```
std::vector< decltype(&foo) > v;
```

or:

```
std::vector< decltype(foo)* > v;
```

or:

```
std::vector< std::function<decltype(foo)> > v;
```

However, all of the above solutions will fail once `foo` is overloaded. Also note that `std::function` is a type-eraser which comes at the cost of a virtual call.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), you can let `std::vector` deduce class template arguments from the initializer list:

```
std::vector v{ foo, bar };
```

Comment: Is on'y the 3rd (`std::function`) option supposed to work, for different functions,  like foo vs bar

Answer (score 22):

To expand on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32888082/4342498) by [Piotr Skotnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3953764/piotr-skotnicki)

```
decltype(foo)
```

Has the type of

```
int(int[], int)
```

Which is not a function pointer.  In order to get a function pointer you either have to use `decltype` with the address of `foo` `decltype(&foo)` or you can add a `*` to the end of the type to declare a pointer to the type of `foo` `decltype(foo)*`

Answer (score 3):

The solution is like this :

```
typedef std::function<int(int[], int)> sf;
std::vector< sf > v2;
```

and it is ok